# React: Fill select menu with json data from another file

Tags: json, reactjs

So I have a `counties.json` file and I have a file with a select input as such:

```
<FormGroup row>
    <Label for="" sm={2}>Site County</Label>
    <Col sm={10}>
        <Input className="form-control" type="select">
            <option>Louth</option>
            <option>Dublin</option>
            <option>Louth</option>
        </Input>
    </Col>
</FormGroup>
```

My goal is to populate the select input with the data in the json file. How can I do this?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to load in json data, you will find it helpful to use the `json-loader` package. This allows you to import your json data into a variable.

To add the package to your project, do:

```
npm install json-loader
```

Once that's been added, and assuming you have a data file called `counties.json`, then you can do the following:

```
import jsonData from './counties.json'
```

Let's say your json data looks something like this:

```
{
  "counties": [
    { "value": "louth",
      "display": "Louth" },
    { "value": "dublin",
      "display": "Dublin" }
  ]
}
```

Then, you can get your counties from the json data like so:

```
const counties = jsonData.counties // This is an array
```

Once you have your array, you can use the array's `map()` function to turn each element of the array (which, in this example, is an object with keys `value` and `display`) into an `<option>`. Make sure, though, because you are rendering an array of options, that you provide a unique key for each option. Just using the `value` will be sufficient. So, in `render()` it will look like this:

```
 <Input className="form-control" type="select">
   { counties.map(c => (<option key={c.value} value={c.value}>{c.display}</option>))}
 </Input>
```

Here is a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/0m9p23rq9n) that demonstrates all of this code in action.

Hope this helps!

`

Comment: Thank you! This worked great! I was going to use the `map()` to add the ``<option>`'s but wasn't sure about importing JSON. Thanks again!

Comment: @TiernO I'm happy that it worked out for you. Happy coding!